# Error "make[4]: *** No rule to make target `mono.exe', needed by `all-am'. Stop." when cross-compiling mono 3.2.x for windows on ubuntu linux

Tags: mono, libtool, cross-compiling

I found that the mono 3.2 or latest stable version released, but it does not have a precompiled version for windows.

So, i tried to compile the source code of the mono 3.2 on ubuntu, and I followed the page at http://www.mono-project.com/Cross-compiling_Mono_for_Windows, 
but it does not work. Which leads me to think that the page is out date.

This is the error I get:

```
  CC     libmini_static_la-mini-windows.lo
../../../mono/mini/mini-windows.c: In function 'mono_chain_signal':
../../../mono/mini/mini-windows.c:89: warning: unused variable 'ctx'
../../../mono/mini/mini-windows.c:88: warning: unused variable 'signal'
  CXXLD  libmini-static.la
  CC     mono_boehm-main.o
../../../mono/mini/main.c:98: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
  CCLD   mono-boehm.exe
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/eglib/src:/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs:/mono-3.2.0/lib:/mono-3.2.0/bin'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
  CC     main.o
../../../mono/mini/main.c:98: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
  CCLD   monow.exe
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/eglib/src:/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs:/mono-3.2.0/lib:/mono-3.2.0/bin'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `mono.exe', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono/mini'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows/mono'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rocky/dev/mono-3.2.0/build-cross-windows'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After that, I googled it, but there was no any additional info which was useful or helpful.

Are there anyone that can tech me how to cross compile the mono 3.2 or latest version for windows on Ubuntu or any other linux version?

Comment: you think it is outdated because the instructions don't work for you, however you don't give any details about the error you get that makes you think that it doesn't work, can you provide those details?

Comment: are you compile the last stable version of mono for windows on linux success?? and does you just following the document at http://www.mono-project.com/Cross-compiling_Mono_for_Windows.

Comment: if u successed. what version of linux on your pc? and does you do something pre-work for it?or something for prepare the Environment that what i missing?

Comment: I didn't say I succeeded, I said "if you didn't succeed, please post the error you got"

Comment: hi,knocte, i have uploaded the compile log ,do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

This [build fix](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ebfd12313e72fd2c3a973ce32e77bcc34d36e50d) (which was committed today) added a `mono.exe` target, could you try updating your mono tree to HEAD (master) and test again?

Comment: ok,thanks. i'll test it next week. then i will give some feedback of it.

Comment: ,i just test the patch and that have another error.like this:

Comment: I didn't tell you to test the patch, I told you to test latest master branch

Comment: maybe i make the commnents some error. But,i just get the lastest master branch to test the new build fix.

Answer (score 0):

i just test the patch and that have another error.like this:

../../../mono/mini/main.c:98: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
  CCLD   monow.exe
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/home/rocky/dev/mono/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:`/home/rocky/dev/mono/mono/build-cross-windows/eglib/src:/home/rocky/dev/mono/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs:/mono-3.3.0-master-254026e/lib:/mono-3.3.0-master-254026e/bin'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
ln -sf mono-sgen.exe mono.exe
make[4]: *** no rule to create target "mono-sgen" needed by "mono" stop。

Answer (score 0):

Test master release.

```
  CC     main.o
  CCLD   monow.exe
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
libtool: link: Could not determine the host path corresponding to
libtool: link:   `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/eglib/src:/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini/.libs:/mono-3.3.0-master-31c9c1b/lib:/mono-3.3.0-master-31c9c1b/bin'
libtool: link: Continuing, but uninstalled executables may not work.
ln -sf mono-sgen.exe mono.exe
make[4]: *** Sem regra para processar o alvo `mono-sgen', necessário por `mono'.  Pare.
make[4]: Saindo do diretório `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini'
make[3]: ** [all] Erro 2
make[3]: Saindo do diretório `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/mono/mini'
make[2]: ** [all-recursive] Erro 1
make[2]: Saindo do diretório `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows/mono'
make[1]: ** [all-recursive] Erro 1
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/opt/mono/src/mono/build-cross-windows'
make: ** [all] Erro 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Test with last master release.

ln -sf mono-sgen.exe mono.exe make[4]: * no rule to create target "mono-sgen" needed by "mono" stop